# Eigen::Ref and const_cast

Tags: c++, reference, eigen, const-cast, const-reference

In C++ I can use `const_cast` to convert a `const Eigen::VectorXd&` object to an `Eigen::VectorXd&` one. I wonder if it's possible to do the same with `Eigen::Ref` objects, i.e., **is there a way to convert a `const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>&` object to an `Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXd>&` one?** If not, is there a workaround to modify an object passed as a `const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXd>&`?

Comment: you can cast a constant reference to a non-constant reference, but modifying a const object is undefined behavior in any case. Why do you not change the signature to pass a non-const ref?

Comment: In my specific case, I must use a function that uses a non-const reference to a vector for efficiency reasons, and that ensures as a post-condition that the input vector doesn't get changed. Also, I'm sure that there's no undefined behavior because such function is used "internally", and I know that the variables I pass as const are actually non-const!

Comment: Anyway, I'm curious about an answer to my question, and I'm confident that my specific use case is the right one for using `const_cast`.